# Application fails to find XSD file using One-Jar

Tags: java, maven, xsd, executable-jar

I am using One-Jar's maven plugin to package my java into one jar with all it's dependencies.

The project has a resource called schema.xsd.

when I run the jar file using `java -jar myJar.one-jar` I get the following error:

```
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
 'jar:file:/../lib/myJar.one-jar.jar!/lib/myJar.jar!/schema.xsd', because 1) could not find 
the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not 
<xsd:schema>.
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Note: the application has a log4j.properties as a resource and it recognizes it.

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure the Jar url connection handling implementation in the jre cannot handle more than one level of nesting (that url has 2 '!' characters in it).  not sure how one-jar handles reading the class files out of the nested jars, but you may need to extract the xsd to a temp file before you can use it.

personally, i generally use the maven assembly plugin with the "jar-with-dependencies" goal, which works just fine unless you have conflicting files in one or your jars.

Comment: The One-Jar is supposed to know how to deal with the multiple '!' characters. See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-onejar/).

Comment: @summerbulb - actually, according to that link, it seems that onejar uses a custom url scheme which doesn't use the multiple '!' chars

Comment: Looks like you're right. But that only make the problem even more weired.